# Using DateRange with Charts on Angular page

Tags: angularjs, daterangepicker

Simple question.

I have several charts on a page of my angular app.

I'd like to add a date range picker to the page that will pass dates into each chart controller to filter the range of data on each chart.

Is it best to make the date range picker a parent controller to the charts or is there a better way to update the charts on the page. Would it better for example to add a watch to the charts to look for changes in the date?

Still quite new to angular so some high level advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I thought the good idea is to keep the watch in the child (your chart) controllers.

The child controllers (whoever wants to update the chart) should do the task when the date-range of `$parent scope` updates.

I would also suggest you to go for `broadcast`: **[Angularjs watch for change in parent scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838745/angularjs-watch-for-change-in-parent-scope#answer-17839230)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Conceptually this pattern seems similar to firing an event and consuming it in the child controllers. I guess my thinking was along the right lines but it's good to get some confirmation before spending a lot of time getting it to work.